# стандартная проверка токена laravel - странное условие

Tags: php, laravel, csrf

в Laravel есть класс VerifyCsrfToken, в котором определена функция handle, которая ловит request и проверяет соответствие токена клиента и сервера, после добавляет в response куку, иначе throw error.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (
        $this->isReading($request) || //проверяет метод формы на соотв. из массива ['HEAD','GET',...]
        $this->runningUnitTests() ||
        $this->shouldPassThrough($request) ||
        $this->tokensMatch($request)
    ){
        return $this->addCookieToResponse($request, $next($request));
    }

    throw new TokenMismatchException;
}
```

Смотрим на условие и видим, что проверяется 4 функции, приоритет при || начинается слева, то есть (здесь скорее всего, я ошибаюсь) у tokenMatch самый маленький приоритет и в случае, если первые 3 функции вернут true, тогда эта функция не будет учитываться в условии, что плохо.

И собственно вопрос, для гуру-laravel, мои рассуждения верны?

Comment: Неправильно сформулировал вопрос - через xdebug ворваться в функцию проверки токена не получается, из-за этого, такое ощущение будто токен вообще не проверяется.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Главное - да, ваши рассуждения верны. Если любой из первых 3 методов вернёт `true`, то `tokensMatch` даже не будет вызываться. Это применимо к любому PHP-коду.

Теперь посмотрим, является ли это ошибкой или так запланировано. Если запланировано, то зачем и не является ли это угрозой.

```
$this->isReading($request) || //проверяет метод формы на соотв. из массива ['HEAD','GET',...]
```

Проверяет, является ли текущий запрос читающим. Напомню, что согласно спецификации `HTTP` запросы типов `GET`, `HEAD` не должны изменять состояние системы. А раз они не меняют состояние системы - то их банально и не нужно защищать от `CSRF` атак.

```
$this->runningUnitTests() ||
```

На самом деле костыль, обычно код не должен различать, запущен он в окружении юнит-тестов или нет. Видимо, так было проще. Во всяком случае суть в том, что для запуска из юнит-тестов проверка всегда проходит.

```
$this->shouldPassThrough($request) ||
```

Здесь без чтения исходника мне сложно сказать, что проверяется. [Исходник](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php)
Ага, проверяется список исключений для URI, для которых проверку CSRF надо пропустить. По-умолчанию список пуст, но возможность отстрелить себе ногу есть.

```
$this->tokensMatch($request)
```

Наконец, если запрос что-то хочет изменить, не в окружении юнит-тестов и не в списке исключений, то проверяем валидность токена.

На мой взгляд всё логично, ошибки в безопасности здесь нет. `tokensMatch` действительно должен вызываться в самом конце.

Потенциальная проблема с `isReading`. Многие люди не учитывают семантику `GET` запросов и делают, например, удаление сущности ссылкой из-за удобства написания простой ссылки, а не целой формы. Не надо так делать.

Answer (score 0):

по поводу лары сказать не могу, но..

> если первые 3 функции вернут true

почему?
тут вообще нет приоритетов, расчеты идут слева направо, как только встретится первый true дальше проверяться ничего не будет